# Finding the closest element to a function in a normed space containing functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $B=\{f\in c[1,0]|\forall 0\leq x\leq 1 : f(x) \geq 0\}$. Given $f\in c[0,1]$, find the closest element in $B$ under the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm.

I can see something similar to this question in the second part of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794266/a-close-convex-of-mathbb-r-with-x-geq-0), only in this case its the closest element to a function and not a number.Is it still a similar method?

Furthermore i think the author of the question meant to ask for a $g\in c[1,0]$ S.T. $g$ might not be an element of $B$ that is g can be smaller then 0. Is this a correct assumption?

What would be a good way for solving this?

Will the closest element be the closet under the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm as well, given $1\leq p<\infty$?

Comment: what about $$ g(x) := \max(f(x),0)$$

Comment: Will that hold for a function that is sometimes greater than 0 and sometimes smaller than 0 in $c[1,0]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some $f \in C[0,1]$. Set $$g(x) := \max(f(x),0),$$ then clearly $g \in B$. To see that this is the closest element in B, look at $$ \|f-g\|_2 = \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - g(x)|^2 dx = \int_{[f\geq 0]} |f(x)-g(x)|^2 + \int_{[f<0]} |f(x)-g(x)|^2$$
Obviously, on the set $[f\geq 0]$ we have $f=g$ such that the first integral vanishes. But on set where f is negative, the closest we can get with any function in $B$ is 0. So $g$ minimizes both of the above integrals.

Comment: Great. Thanks. and if I understand correctly, this will hold for any other p- norm since the only thing changing is the power of two to p?